# Simple question but I keep getting answer wrong..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, percentages, word-problem

I am not sure why I am getting this wrong or what the right approach is.. The book answer is 9 and I got 8 machines for part a). Can someone explain how the book answer is 9? What I did was say that since the machine is only 95% reliable, each cycle is extended by 5% so instead of a cycle time being 5 mins it is 5.25 mins long..Did that for all the products and found how much time is in 8 hours for 250 days.

[image]

Comment: Do you include scrap rate of 3%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part A would need $5\cdot 25\,000$ minutes machine time per year in total, parts B and C similarly. Add the three figures up and divide the sum by $0.95$ to account for down-time and by $0.97$ to account for scrap. You will arrive at $982094.41$ minutes envisaged machine time. Divide this by the number of minutes in a year ($120\,000$), and you obtain $8.184$. This shows that you need $9$ machines to be on the safe side.

Thereby the word "scrap" was interpreted as follows: $3\%$ of the produced pieces are faulty and have to be thrown away.

Comment: oooo I wasn't dividing by scrap rate...that is why I was off. I thought scrap rate meant how much machine can be sold for at end of its life. What does that mean in this situation?

Comment: @Raynos: See my edit.

Comment: got it! That means we need addition 1.03.

Comment: @Raynos: Adding $3\%$ or dividing by $0.97$ gives approximately the same. But only dividing by $0.97$ is correct. Think about the case where the scrap rate is $50\%$!